# Scrapy / OpenSSL scraping HTTPS sites: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context'

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, scrapy

I was trying to crawl an HTTPS site but got the following error:

```
2016-05-14 20:11:21 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.anHTTPSsite.com/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 60, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 281, in download_request
    method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1594, in request
    endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1578, in _getEndpoint
    return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1454, in endpointForURI
    uri.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 57, in creatorForNetloc
    return ScrapyClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode("ascii"), self.getContext())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 54, in getContext
    return self.getCertificateOptions().getContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1618, in getContext
    self._context = self._makeContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1656, in _makeContext
    ctx.set_session_id(sessionName)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 719, in set_session_id
    _lib.SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context'
```

However, when I try to crawl its HTTP version(simply changing the protocol in the URL from `https` to `http`), the error is gone.

**EDIT**: `scrapy version -v` output:

```
Scrapy    : 1.1.0
lxml      : 3.4.4.0
libxml2   : 2.9.2
Twisted   : 16.1.1
Python    : 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) - [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]
pyOpenSSL : 16.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015)
Platform  : Linux-4.2.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.10-wily
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: 2 comments: Scrapy 1.0 does not support Python 3, try upgrading to 1.1. Scrapy 1.1 works better with HTTPS websites, assuming you use recent enough versions of twisted, pyopenssl and cryptography. If it still fails, paste the output of `scrapy version -v`

Comment: @paultrmbrth Sorry for the delay. The problem is still there. I have included the output in the post.

Comment: SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context call looks recent in pyopenssl. I don't know what the issue and can't help you further now (I'm away from computer for 2 weeks). Try Scrapy-users mailing list or ask the twisted people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It appears to be related to recent changes in pyOpenSSL. Downgrading to 0.15.1 solved it for me. Before doing so, I recommend looking at the changelog of pyOpenSSL to see if you feel that downgrading is worth it.

On OSX, this should work:

```
sudo pip install pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
```